# What is the counterpart of Pythons (.append) in Java

Tags: java, arrays, list, append

So i've created a list in Java called movieInfo and i want to slowly add stuff to it as my program runs. I know in Python this is done by typing movieList.append("whatever you want to add"), but i cant seem to find out how to do it in Java.

```
movieInfo = new String [4];
```

Comment: you can try  List<String> movieInfo = new ArrayList<>(); movieInfo.add(“something“)

Comment: "i've created a list in Java called movieInfo" and `movieInfo = new String [4];` don't match. You didn't create a _list_ but an _array_. See Matthias' comment on how to use a list.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually several solutions.
You can create a copy of this array with a bigger length as shown in this code:

```
movieInfo = Arrays.copyOf(movieInfo , movieInfo.length +1) 
movieInfo[movieInfo.length - 1] = "movie name";
```

or more simply use Vector or ArrayList which have a method add

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList (length);
list.add("movie name");
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have is not a list, but an *array*. To declare a list, you can do something like `List<ObjectType> list = new ArrayList<>();`, where `ObjectType` is the type of the objects you will be putting into the list.

To add elements, call the `.add` method:

```java
list.add("movie");
```